# RelationshipEntity not persisted

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm having problems with relation

```
@RelationshipEntity(type = RelTypes.Tag.TAG_ON_OBJECT_EVALUATION)
public class TagOnObjectEvaluation
{
  @StartNode
  private Mashup taggableObject;

  @EndNode
  private Tag tag;

  // Other fields, getters and setters
}
```

In both the entities involved (`Mashup` and `Tag`), I have this field (with opposite Direction)

```
@RelatedToVia(type = RelTypes.Tag.TAG_ON_OBJECT_EVALUATION,
      direction = Direction.INCOMING /*Direction.OUTGOING*/)
  private Set<TagOnObjectEvaluation> tagOnObjectEvaluations =
      new HashSet<TagOnObjectEvaluation>();
```

Then, I have various service class to manage `Tag`, `Mashup` and `TagOnObjectEvaluation`. The class under test now is the latter.
Note: the name is a bit confusing and it's a legacy from the previous coder, you can read DAO as Service. Also GenericNeo4jDAOImpl (again, read it as GenericServiceNeo4jImpl) simply defines standard methods for entities management (`create()`, `find()`, `update()`, `delete()`, `fetch()` )

```
@Service
public class TagOnObjectEvaluationDAONeo4jImpl extends
    GenericNeo4jDAOImpl<TagOnObjectEvaluation> implements
    TagOnObjectEvaluationDAO
{
  @Autowired
  private TagOnObjectEvaluationRepository repository;

  public TagOnObjectEvaluationDAONeo4jImpl()
  {
    super(TagOnObjectEvaluation.class);
  }

  public TagOnObjectEvaluationDAONeo4jImpl(
      Class<? extends TagOnObjectEvaluation> entityClass)
  {
    super(entityClass);
  }

  @Override
  public TagOnObjectEvaluation create(TagOnObjectEvaluation t)
  {
    Transaction tx = template.getGraphDatabaseService().beginTx();
    TagOnObjectEvaluation savedT = null;
    try
    {
      // This is to enforce the uniqueness of the relationship. I know it can fail in many ways, but this is not a problem ATM 
      savedT =
          template.getRelationshipBetween(
              t.getTaggableObject(), t.getTag(),
              TagOnObjectEvaluation.class,
              RelTypes.Tag.TAG_ON_OBJECT_EVALUATION);
      if (savedT == null)
        savedT = super.create(t);
      tx.success();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      tx.failure();
      savedT = null;
    }
    finally
    {
      tx.finish();
    }
    return savedT;
  }
}
```

It seems pretty straightforward until now.
But when I'm trying to persist a `RelationshipEntity` instance, I have many problems.

```
  @Test
  public void testRelationshipEntityWasPersisted()
  {
    TagOnObjectEvaluation tagOnObjectEvaluation = new TagOnObjectEvaluation(taggedObject, tag);

    tagOnObjectEvaluationDao.create(tagOnObjectEvaluation);
    assertNotNull(tagOnObjectEvaluation.getId());
    LOGGER.info("TagOnObjectEvaluation id = " + tagOnObjectEvaluation.getId());

    tagDao.fetch(tag);
    assertEquals(1, tag.getTaggedObjectsEvaluations().size());
  }
```

The last test fail: the size is 0 and not 1. Also, although it seems that the entity is correctly stored (it gets an `id` assigned), if I'm navigating the db later on there is no track of it at all.
I've also tried to add the relationship in a different way, using the sets of the involved nodes; f.e.

```
tag.getTaggedObjectsEvaluations().add(tagOnObjectEvaluation);
tagDao.update(tag);
```

but with no improvements at all.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but I think in your `Mashape` entity, the direction should be `OUTOING`. Could you try it?

Comment: you're right, make it an answer so that I can accept it and add comments on what is going on

Comment: Why did you use ***Ŗ*** in the title?

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc wtf, I thought it was my dirty screen. I don't even know how to do such a thing again :S

Comment: @tigerjack89 You should probably edit it out because it makes this question hard to google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the **direction** of the relationship in your entity `Mashape`, (entity corresponding to the `@StartNode` of your `@RelationshipEntity` `TagOnObjectEvaluation`).

```
@NodeEntity
class Mashape {

   // ...
   @RelatedToVia(type = RelTypes.Tag.TAG_ON_OBJECT_EVALUATION, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
   private Set<TagOnObjectEvaluation> tagOnObjectEvaluations = new HashSet<TagOnObjectEvaluation>();    

}
```

Just point that according to the [specifications](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-neo4j/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/annotation/RelatedToVia.html) of `@RelatedToVia` `spring-data-neo4j` annotation, the direction by default is `OUTGOING`, so you really don't need to specify the direction in this case. This also should be correct:

```
   @RelatedToVia(type = RelTypes.Tag.TAG_ON_OBJECT_EVALUATION)
   private Set<TagOnObjectEvaluation> tagOnObjectEvaluations = new HashSet<TagOnObjectEvaluation>();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep, it seems that I've the directions inverted. From what I've seen thanks to your suggestion, when you use a `@RelationshipEntity` class, the related entities should have a reference to the relationship with `@RelatedToVia(direction = Direction.X)`, where X=OUTGOING for the entity marked as `@StartNode` in the `@RelationshipEntity` class, while X=INCOMING for the entity annotated with `@EndNode`. Do you know why? It seems quite the opposite to the real case.

Comment: Yep, I think it deppeds on how you represent the relationships in your model. For me, this is the "logical" order in most of the cases. Glad to help you!